# How to enqueue scripts and styles only when there are needed?

Tags: theme-development

I have page created based on ACF and flexible fields layout. In my theme I have some JS scripts like masonry, fancybox, lazyload. For now im using standard `wp_enqueue_style` in `function.php` file. Is there any clever way to enqueue scripts only if certain block from ACF is chosen, and only once if this block was inserted earlier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to enqueue a specific script on `post.php`, which is triggered by the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
if ( in_array( get_current_screen()->base, [ 'post' ] ) ) {
    // Load scripts only on the post edit page.
    wp_enqueue_script( PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_ROOT_URL . 'resources/js/script.js', [], PLUGIN_VERSION, false );
}
```

Instead of the check I do, you could retrieve the post's content and scan it for the block you require. Like so:

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
    $post = get_post();
    if ( $post && has_blocks( $post ) ) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        $postContainsBlock = ... // Search $blocks array for the required block.
            
        if ( $postContainsBlock ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_ROOT_URL . 'resources/js/script.js', [], PLUGIN_VERSION, false );
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the code above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: can I use wp_enqueue_script directly in my block.php file which is in specific flexible layout?

Comment: @DamianP. I think you can! But since I'm not sure I would recommend to try it out ;-).

Comment: It's works :) The good point is that if I add multiple enqueues, there will be enqueued only one, first script, so if I add 100 layouts, script will be enqueued once. The bad point is that script is automatically added to footer, so after my JS script in layout.

Comment: @DamianP. Have you set the last parameter of `wp_enqueue_scripts` to `false`? Because then the script should be added to the `<head>`.